# iSeries Export to CSV

Tags: csv, ibm-midrange, control-language

Is there an iSeries command to export the data in a table to CSV format?

I know about the Windows utilities, but since this needs to be run automatically I need to run this from a CL program.

Comment: Are you still here? I would be very grateful igf you could provide me with some help on the exact same topic

Comment: could i please get some extra help on this? @nearly_lunchtime

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use CPYTOIMPF and specify the TOSTMF option to place a CSV file on the IFS.
Example: 
CPYTOIMPF FROMFILE(DBFILE) TOSTMF('/outputfile.csv') STMFCODPAG(*PCASCII) RCDDLM(*CRLF)

Comment: You can also use this command with the TOFILE keyword instead of the TOSTMF keyword to load a CSV file in a library.

Comment: So that copies your file to the ifs . How are you supposed to take the file from the ifs and into a folder in your pc?

Comment: could i please get some extra help on this? @mike

Answer (score 1):

If you want the data to be downloaded directly to a PC, you can use the "Data Transfer from iSeries" function of IBM iSeries Client Access to create a .CSV file. In the file output details dialog, set the file type to `Comma Separated Variable (CSV)`.

You can save the transfer description to be reused later.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a trigger. The iSeries Client Access software wont do since that is a windows application, what I understand is that you need the data to be exported each time that the file is written. Check [this link](http://www.tylogix.com/Articles/TriggerTechniques.htm) to know more about triggers.

Answer (score 0):

You are going to need FTP to perform that action. 
If your iSeries shop uses ZMOD/FTP your shortest solution is a few lines of code away -- 3 lines to be exact -- the three lines are to Start FTP, Put DBF, and finally, End FTP.

IF you don't use ZMOD/FTP:
- You could use native FTP/400 to accomplish what you need to do, but it is quite involved!!!
- you may probably need to use an RPGLE program to parse, format, and move, data into a "flatfile", then use native FTP/400 to FTP the file out
- and yes, a CL will need as a wrapper!

Comment: FTP might or might not be needed. Without knowing the network connectivity, we have no way to know.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it all in one very simple CL program:

- CPYTOIMPF the file TOSTMF -> the cvs file will be in the IFS
- FTP the file elsewhere (to a server or a PC)

It works like a charm